Творительный падеж при прилагательном
Ответьте, пожалуйста, могут ли при прилагательном стоять зависимые слова в творительном падеже со значением субъекта действия или инструмента? Я всегда думала, что если такое слово имеется, то перед нами именно причастие, а не прилагательное (так пишут в словарях обычно).

Жена предана мужем (муж предал жену)


Жертва оправдана высшим замыслом (замысел оправдал жертву)

Знаю, что во втором случае у слова переносное значение, но мне кажется, что причастие тоже может иметь переносное значение, так как слово сохраняет возможность управлять творительным падежом, таким образом показывается процессуальность, характерная для причастий, а не прилагательных (прилагательное обозначает постоянный признак).

Смею предположить, что у лингвистов разные подходы к этим частям речи. Поэтому слова со значением признака по действию называют прилагательными, которые "ведут себя по-причастному".

субъект действия:
любимый зрителем фильм
одержимый страстью

объект действия:
нищий духом
местами интересный
я сыт этим
недовольный итогом
богатая деревом
холодный умом


Заметим, что одержимый страстью и нищий духом конструкции однотипные, но почему-то одна воспринимается как субъектная, а вторая как объектная.
Тут дело как раз в наличии глаголов типа одержать. То же и с любимым фильмом. Так что вопрос неоднозначный - что к чему относить, к прилагательным или причастиям

А как быть ? Чем считать?

Ответ ИРЯ
Критерии разграничения причастий и отглагольных прилагательных — одна из актуальных проблем современной русистики: лингвисты признают, что во многих контекстах невозможно строго различить причастие и прилагательное. Так, в статье С. С. Сая «Причастие», опубликованной на сайте «Русская корпусная грамматика» (ссылка на страницу: http://rusgram.ru/) говорится: «Провести четкую границу между «еще причастиями» и «уже прилагательными», переставшими быть словоформами глаголов, принципиально невозможно. Способность к адъективации — это неотъемлемое свойство, заложенное в самой природе русских причастий; практически любое русское причастие в той или иной степени способно его демонстрировать» [см. статья «Причастие», § 5.2.2].
Разумеется, сложности с разграничением причастий и прилагательных неминуемо приводят к сложностям в их правописании. Составители орфографических словарей и справочников по правописанию по сей день пытаются решить эту проблему. Прежде (например, в «Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 г.) правило написания н или нн в кратких формах отглагольных прилагательных / причастий прошедшего времени строилось на следующем противопоставлении: в кратких причастиях пишется только н, в кратких отглагольных прилагательных — только нн. Однако, как отмечают специалисты, такое правило сложно в применении, к тому же оно не учитывало реальной практики письма. По этой причине специалисты в области орфографии приняли решение допустить написание н в кратких отглагольных прилагательных (иными словами, в некоторых кратких отглагольных прилагательных теперь допустимо написание как нн, так и н; напомним, Правилами 1956 г. такое написание предусмотрено не было). Так, в полном академическом справочнике «Правила русской орографии и пунктуации» под ред. В. В. Лопатина 2006 г. (электронная версия справочника доступна в сети Интернет на странице с адресом: https://orfogrammka.ru/) допускается написание одной буквы н в кратких прилагательных [см. общее правило и подробное примечание в § 102].
Рекомендация относительно правописания интересующего Вас слова ограниченный, содержащаяся в «Русском орфографическом словаре» под ред. В. В. Лопатина, продиктована необходимостью учесть, с одной стороны, семантику слова ограниченный (ведь, как Вы совершенно справедливо отметили, в примере её интересы ограничены домом и детьми слово ограничены использовано в значении, свойственном прилагательному, а не причастию), с другой стороны, грамматическую сочетаемость этого прилагательного (не причастия!). Пример её интересы ограничены домом и детьми демонстрирует, что краткая форма прилагательного ограниченный может употребляться в, на первый взгляд, типичной для причастия позиции — с зависимым словом в творительном падеже — и писаться с одной н, но являться при этом прилагательным, не переходить в разряд причастий (первостепенную роль в данном случае играет семантика слова). Аналогично (при зависимом слове в творительном падеже, но с одной н) пишется, например, краткая форма прилагательного оправданный (ср.: оправданный, но: затраты оправданы важностью проекта).
В заключение можем порекомендовать Вам орфографический академический ресурс «Академос» (ссылка на страницу: https://orfo.ruslang.ru/), имеющий статус официальной публикации Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН. В настоящее время это, безусловно, наиболее авторитетный источник орфографической нормы, живо реагирующий на те или иные изменения в русском языке. Искренне надеемся, что ресурс будет полезен для Вас.
С уважением
Евгений Базаров, сотрудник отдела культуры русской речи ИРЯ РАН

«Пример её интересы ограничены домом и детьми...»?

@shampar что конкретно вас интересует в этом примере?

Аскетичнось в пунктуации.

А-а, вы имеете в виду кавычки?Да...странно.

См.ответ Грамоты.ру https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/318758

ОТВЕТ
(1) Подсудимая оправдана (судом) за недостаточностью улик.
Это краткое причастие, одна буква Н. Прямое значение действия, дополнение судом можно подобрать или оно присутствует в тексте.
(2) Жертва оправдана высшим замыслом (замысел оправдал жертву).
Это краткое прилагательное, одна бува Н, есть дополнение в Т. п. Переносное значение (замысел не может оправдать жертву).
(3)  Такая жертва оправданна (понятна, логична)
Это краткое прилагательное две бувы НН, нет дополнения в Т. п. Переносное значение.
Пояснение
А это как бы моё рабочее "правило":
ГРУППА 1. Парные причастия (Н) и прилагательные 1 (НН)
Полная форма у парных слов одна и та же — форма страдательного причастия прошедшего времени (НН), а краткая форма разная: одна буква Н в кратком причастии (признак по действию) и две буквы НН в кратком прилагательном (качественный признак).
Прилагательные из этой группы отличаются от причастия метафорическим (ПЕРЕНОСНЫМ) значением, что несложно определить НА СЛУХ: На свете чудеса рассеяны повсюду (И.А. Крылов). Ах, король, как рассеянны вы! (Н.Агнивцев).
Кроме того, прилагательные имеют сравнительную степень, в отличие от причастий: Он стал еще рассеяннее.
Для ПРИЧАСТИЯ можно подобрать зависимое слово в Т.п. (производитель или орудие действия): Тучи рассеяны ветром. ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ может иметь усилительные слова (наречия степени очень и др.), а также возможны однородные отношения с другими прилагательными:  Вы очень рассеянны и невнимательны.
Примечание.  Но эти синтаксические признаки необязательно присутствуют в тексте.
ГРУППА 2. Прилагательные 2 (Н)
Эти прилагательные не имеют парного причастия (заплаканный, заржавленный), но в краткой форме в них пишется одна буква Н, как у причастий.
Розенталь §48, пункт 7
ГРУППА 3. Прилагательные 3 (Н и НН)
Особенную трудность для анализа представляет  группа прилагательных 3 (Н и НН). Здесь определиться с выбором Н и НН еще сложнее: эти прилагательные (с переносным значением!) могут иметь ДВЕ ФОРМЫ письма (Н и НН) в зависимости от вида синтаксической КОНСТРУКЦИИ. Другими словами, он могут вести себя как прилагательные (НН) или как причастия (Н) при наличии дополнения. В то же время по наличию переносного значения их приходится  отличать от причастий с прямым значением действия. У Розенталя, кроме  дополнения, говорится еще об инфинитиве.
ВЫВОД
Другими словами, надо четко прописать СИНТАКСИС таких прилагательных с Н, а не надеяться на правильное понимание. Сомневаться могут лингвисты, но  не пользователи, которым нужно конкретное правило и без сомнений.
Краткие прилагательные с Н отличаются от кратких причастий с Н по переносному значению, но при этом они сходны с ними по морфологическим и синтаксическим признакам. Их нужно перечислить, чтобы пользователи могли практически использовать этот материал. Пока он изложен у Розенталя (пункт 7 и 8) и в ПАС под ред. Лопатина § 102.
В частности, краткие формы прилагательных на -нный пишутся с одним Н, если эти прилагательные требуют зависимых слов и не имеют формы сравнительной степени. Некоторые прилагательные с Н образуются от непереходных глаголов и причастиями быть не могут: глаза заплаканы, железо заржавлено.

Честно, я не вижу разницы: суд оправдал или замысел оправдал. Для меня обе эти фразы одинаково прямолинейны.

Посмотрите толковый словарь  для глагола оправдать https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=оправдать&mode=slovari&dicts[]=42 в пункте 1 указано прямое значение, а остальные переносные.

Может, и переносное значение, но фраза вполне нормальная, я об этом.

Короче, нужен реальный суд и письменный приговор, вот это прямое значение.

@ТатьянаАлексеевна, о творительном падеже пишет и сотрудник ИРЯ, об этом также сказано в словаре. Что касается разграничения прилагательных и причастий в творительном падеже, об этом Sharon ясно изложила а своем ответе.

Мнение по ответу сотрудника отдела культуры русской речи ИРЯ РАН

Специалист  говорит о правилах 1956 года или ПАС, но почему-то не говорит о правилах Розенталя:

Розенталь §48, пункт 7
Примечание. Некоторые отглагольные прилагательные пишутся в 
полной форме с двумя н (нн), а в краткой — с одним н, 
подобно причастиям, с которыми их сближает наличие приставки 
и вид производящего глагола: заплаканные глаза — глаза 
заплаканы; заржавленные ножи — ножи заржавлены; поношенное 
платье — платье поношено. То же в сложных словах: 
общепризнанное превосходство — превосходство общепризнано; 
свежезамороженные ягоды — ягоды свежезаморожены.

8. Некоторые прилагательные допускают двоякое написание 
краткой формы в зависимости от значения и конструкции. Ср.:
Сестра намерена вскоре уехать (‘имеет намерение’ — в 
сочетании с инфинитивом).
Его дерзость намеренна (‘нарочита’ — без инфинитива).
Мы преданы Родине (в сочетании с формой дательного падежа).
Старые друзья всегда преданны (без дополнения).
Наши легкоатлеты уверены в победе (с дополнением).
Движения гимнастов легки и уверенны (без дополнения)


И вообще ответ туманный, он как бы оправдывает "конформизм". Приведу еще раз ссылку на Орфографические войны.

Там как раз говорится о таком конформизме. Здесь нужна твердая уверенность в том, что правило необходимо, а то все будут писать как слышат. А также говорить о том, что  "слово находится в позиции нейтрализации!".
Вот чтобы избежать подобных войн и откровенно безграмотного письма, и нужно четкое правило. А иначе пусть посмотрят в Карту слов или заглянут в Сеть, где разных мнений "воз и маленькая тележка". Разве можно это считать нормальным?

Так все же это причастия или прилагательные?

Посмотрите мой второй ответ.

Меня больше волнует вопрос, где именно написано о том, что такие прилагательные могут управлять творительным падежом (это традиционно причастный падеж).

Что значит причастный падеж?  В прямом значении суд выносит приговор, а в переносном люди дают моральную оценку, то есть это тот же приговор, но значение переносное.

В разных источниках на интернет-пространстве пишут о том, что для причастия характерно наличие зависимого слова в творительном падеже. Я нигде не видела, чтобы так говорили о прилагательном. Где можно об этом почитать?

Тогда считайте, что прилагательное с Н также себя ведет, то есть требует Т. п.   для обозначения производителя действия. Прилагательное с Н это как бы причастие, но только значение переносное, поэтому его называют прилагательным. Однако есть особенность - обязательное наличие Т. п.  в тексте. И какая вам разница, что пишут в пространстве, если нужно понять правило, обязательное для исполнения.

Мне нужно четко понимать, может прилагательное употребляться с творительным падежом или нет. Если может, то где я могу об этом почитать? Не могу же я на слово верить...

А если не творительный падеж, а другой, то как?

Вот это как раз и требует дополнительного пояснения. В ПАС у Лопатина есть кое-что § 102. Краткие формы прилагательных на -нный пишутся с одним н, если эти прилагательные требуют зависимых слов и не имеют формы сравнительной степени. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52  А в словаре указан только Т. п., этого недостаточно.

Я не могу понять, почему это прилагательное в переносном значении, а не причастие, если тут творительный инструмента.

Я о том, почему причастие не может быть использовано в переносном значении? Я не встречала такой информации. Сравните: цель не может быть оправдана средствами - средства не могут оправдать цель. Средства совершают действие над целью. Это типично причастная логика, но должны считать прилагательным...

Это я уже объясняла, и это аксиома: причастие обозначает реальное/прямое действие, но не переносное. Прямым значение действия является только первое значение глагола по словарю: оправдать в суде, все остальные переносные. В вашем примере 3. что (чем). Признать что-л. допустимым, возможным, непредосудительным

А как насчет "сгорающий в любви"? Явный перенос значения, но ведь это не прилагательное.


перен.; от чего. Испытать глубокое волнение, потрясение от какого-л. сильного чувства. Она Тарквинию с размаха Дает — пощечину. Да, да, Пощечину, Да ведь какую! Сгорел граф Нулин от стыда. Пушкин, Граф Нулин.

